# Balanced sampling with python

Tags: python, dataframe, sampling

I've got a df with 23 columns and 8124 rows. In the first column (named type) there are only two values "e" or "p".
Now I need to create two different df:

- The first df has to contain 5686 rows (70% of the rows circa) and at the same time the number of "e" and "p" must be the same (50% of e and 50% of p).
- The second df has to contain the remaining rows.

IMPORTANT all this rows must be selected RANDOMLY by the original df (no repetition allowed).

Edit: There are not enough rows with element e and p, so i have to sacrifice some istances

Comment: Are the frequencies of "e" and "p" rows in the complete data frame also 50%?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the proportion of 'e' and 'p' you have in the complete dataset. If any of both 'e' or 'p' is less than 2843 (50% of 5686) you won't be able to achieve it, assuming you have this condition fulfilled you can try this:

```
filtered_data = df.groupby(['Col_with_e_and_p']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2843)).reset_index(drop = True)
```

for remaining data you can use this workaround since after grouping the original indices will go:

```
bool_position = df.merge(filtered_data, how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'].str.contains('left_only')
remaining_df = df[bool_position]
```

Comment: It should work, but my problem is not to create the first df with 70% of random rows and same number of e and p rows. But is to create the second that has the remaning rows!

Comment: Ii have updated my answer which gives you the remaining data as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the data frame is such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(8124,23)))
df.insert(0,"x",np.random.choice(['e','p'],8124))
```

If you know the numbers before hand, then one way is to use a list comprehension to get the index of 1/2 of 'e' and 1/2 of 'p'. Then subset the dataframe using this:

```
n = (np.floor(0.7*df.shape[0])/2).astype('int')
2843

idx = np.array([np.random.choice(df.index[df['x']==i],n,replace=False)  for i in ['p','e']]).flatten()

df1 = df.iloc[idx]
df2 = df.iloc[~df.index.isin(idx)]
```